# Cannot extract JSON property from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I have this code

```
request(options, (error, response) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  //console.log( JSON.stringify(data, null, " ") );
  console.log(data);
})
```

Which gives me this output

```
{
 result: 'OK',
 data: {
   body: {
     pdpHeader: [Object],
     overview: [Object],
     hotelWelcomeRewards: [Object],
     propertyDescription: [Object],
     guestReviews: [Object],
     atAGlance: [Object],
     hotelBadge: [Object],
     unavailable: {}
  },
  common: { pointOfSale: [Object], tracking: [Object] }
  },
  transportation: { transportLocations: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  neighborhood: { neighborhoodName: 'Manhattan' }
}
```

Within the actual body of this output there is this:

```
{4 items
"result":"OK"
"data":{2 items
    "body":{14 items
        "pdpHeader":{6 items
            "hotelId":"424023"
            "destinationId":"1506246"
            "pointOfSaleId":"HCOM_US"
```

I want to call out the hotelID number: 424023

I have tried the following a few other modifications to this, but cannot seem to call out the correct object

```
console.log(data.body.pdpHeader.hotelID)
```

But I get the error message

```
console.log(data.body.pdpHeader.hotelID);
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pdpHeader' of undefined
```

Comment: I think you want `data.data.body` .... etc ... I assume the variable holding this object is called `data` ... if it were called `graham` you'd use `graham.data.body` ... does that make sense now? can you see where you went wrong?

Comment: it's not hotelID it's hotelId

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've called your const `data` as well, so you'll either need to destruct or call `.data` again, like so.

### Destruct

You can destruct the propery onto your `data` const like so:

```js
const { data } = JSON.parse(response.body)
// data.body.pdpHeader.hotelID
```

### Assignment

If you don't want to destruct, call `data.data` as per below.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(response.body)
// data.data.body.pdpHeader.hotelID
```